# Python: how to choose a value from a distribution?

Tags: python, distribution

I would like to choose the correspondent value from a distribution

My distribution follows a truncated Levy distribution

```
x = [(r + r0)**(-a)] * exp(−r/κ)
```

The function is

```
def levy(r0, a, k, r):
    return (r + r0)**(-a)*exp(-r/k)
```

I would like to for a given random number `x` find the relative `r`.

For instance

```
r0 = 100  
a = 2
k = 1500

import random
x = random.uniform(0, 1)
### Write a function to find r given x
```

Comment: Are you aware that a lookup in O(N) might imply a non deterministic number of steps? I recommend simply writing the inverse mathematical function.

Comment: @Atterson the problem is to find the inverse of such a function

Comment: Absolutely. But find a mathematician, he will write it in no time. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use the inverse CDF of a Levy found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lévy_distribution#Random_sample_generation)?

Comment: What would be range for `r` ? [0...infinity] ?

Answer (score 0):

Brodaly speaking, what you want is to:

- write the cumulative function, F
- write its inverse, F_inv
- run F_inv(x). This will give you random numbers from your distribution.

If you can't do the first step analytically (), you can at least do it numerically with some given resolution, so you won't get stuck with something non-deterministic.